# How to properly un-escape the included values of include_component?

Tags: php, symfony1

Precondition:

```
escaping_strategy:      true
```

I have installed the **prestaBreadcrumbPlugin**, that outputs the bread html formatted breadcrumbs. The breadcrumbs included in the layout :

```
<?php include_component('prestaBreadcrumb', 'show'); ?>
```

and it displays escaped text.  What is the right way to unescape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try calling `include_component()` with `ESC_RAW` as last parameter?

Comment: Thanks not yet, the plugin seem to be not what I was looking for, but still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to change _show.php in your /plugins/prestaBreadcrumbPlugin/modules/prestaBreadcrumb/templates/ so:

```
<?php echo sfOutputEscaper::unescape($oprestaBreadcrumb->render()) ?>
```